# Looking for libraries which implement sequential minimal optimization in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I want to use SMO (Sequential Minimal Optimization) in order to train an SVM (Support Vector Machine).  Can anyone suggest existing C++ libraries which implement SMO?

I plan to use this to train an SVM to find an object in a picture (probably a human).

Comment: Wow, I'm usually pretty tolerant of non-native speakers, but that question is just confusing.  Surely even google translate could do a better job.  Please try again, and spell out SVM and SMO so we have a better chance of understanding the question.

Comment: From a quick searching, there seems to be very little publicly published code to do that; most of the references I found were articles describing something WAY out of my league!
M.

Comment: @Caspin: I didn't have much trouble reading it, but most of my understanding is based on having googled SMO to figure out what he was talking about.  And there were way too many unrelated SQL articles :/.  Well, it's in plain English now.

Answer (score 4):

1. Visit [this CiteSeer page](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.24.7001).
2. Click "view or download."
3. Copy/paste or otherwise extract C++ code from implementation section (pages 15 onward).

I suspect more careful searching might find an already built copy.  I admit this code is a raw implementation and will probably need some fiddling to make it suitable for incorporation into your own software.  Also, I don't know what kind of licensing applies here.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try [svmlight](http://svmlight.joachims.org/).  I am not sure that it implements SMO, though.  I do know that [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has a java implementation of an SVM classifier using SMO, which may also be helpful to you.  It also includes many other kinds of classifiers, and it is fairly easy to use.

Удачи!

Comment: weka does everything.  It's a bit complex, but insanely full featured.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider Numenta http://www.vitamindinc.com
They have an AI image recognition project that looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Check out LIBSVM (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). I have never used it with C++, but its MATLAB hooks worked flawlessly. In addition, a few papers that I came across used the library as a baseline comparison for their algorithmic improvements to SMO.